# Configure application pools in IIS Express

Tags: wif, iis-express, adfs2.0

Recently I have been using IIS Express and it works really great. However, I have on scenario I am unable to solve.

I am developing a webapp where users should be able to login with their AD account. Since the server which will run the webapp is outside the domain I use ADFS 2.0 as a SSO solution to solve this problem.

To make development for this project easier, I have chosen to use IIS Express when developing.

To be able to exchange claims information with the ADFS 2.0 server from my development environment, I have to configure the application pool for the site to have Load User Profile set to true (like i.e. IIS 7.5). I have searched around the web, and have so far found very little documentation on how to configure application pools in IIS Express.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with ADFS but it's the way WIF uses to sign and encrypt the cookie that will be used to identify the user after the initial sign in. The default implementation in WIF uses DPAPI which relies om the user profile to get key material.

You can override that default and use the machinekey as key material instead. Indeed thats the way it works in NET 4.5 by default precisely because all the issues with DPAPI. Here you have the way to do it in Net 4

http://leastprivilege.com/2012/07/12/machinekey-based-session-protection-for-wif/

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Although, my scenario has changed a bit. I got ADFS 2.0 up and working with a one of the sample applications that came with WIF (yay). The problem is that these applications use Windows authentication. I want to use forms login. I am new to this, so please bear with me. I want to logon my users using form based authentication. Authenticate the user in AD and get information back (Name, emplyeeID) to work with.

Comment: So if you could point me in the right direction, I would very much appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: You have to change the config file on your ADFS server. This should help you: http://www.richardawilson.com/2010/10/adfs-20-login-page.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful stuff! Do I have to use the login page provided with ADFS or is it possible to use the login page from my application? And, how do I fetch the claims in my application? Running .NET4.0 MVC 3

Comment: VimKin, if your question has been answered, accept the response. If you have another question, please post it as a new question instead of creating a conversation in the comments area. Please review the FAQs: http://stackoverflow.com/faq.